# Resolving a type with Structuremap at runtime through a configurable option

Tags: c#, structuremap

I do not have much experience with DI yet, I have a project where I have two implementations of an interface and I want to be able to switch between them after the application has been compiled. I assumed XML config would be the natural choice however that has been deprecated in the current release of Structuremap.

The code that uses the currently hard coded concrete name of one of the implementations always assigns to the interface, so I do not have much code to edit to implement injection, just a few places where the instance is new'ed up. I just do not see how to configure the ability to get one or the other after the app is compiled.

What is the preferred pattern to accomplish this after compilation?